# iMessages split between different devices.

Tags: iphone, ipad, imac, messages

I have a bunch of Apple products. iPad, iMac, iPhone etc. And lately I've been noticing that some of my iMessages show up on one device and not the other.

For example: when my parents text me, I will be out and about. And when I get back home to my iMac, I will see that there were several texts that I didn't receive on my phone but they are on my iMac and iPad or vice versa.

I have feeling this has something to do with what the address the iMessage clients are using on each device. How to figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive`, check which addresses/numbers under `You can be reached by iMessage at` are checked and that the same ones are checked on all your devices. If there are differences that can explain what you're seeing as depending on which address the sender is using will then determine which device(s) you'll receive it on.

Remember that you don't necessarily know how the sender is choosing to contact you.  Are they starting a fresh conversation and choosing from one of your iMessage registered addresses?  Are they replying to one of your messages which may have been started by a different contact address etc?  It can get really confusing, but the key is to go through all your devices and ensure that they are *listening* to and *sending* from the most appropriate address.

Comment: I would agree that you likely don't have an email address on your phone under messages. This would be the most simple and easy to fix cause. Otherwise, perhaps more complicated problems such as a lack of data connection on the iPhone could be at the root. You also could try turning iMessage off on the phone, and then back on.

Comment: That was it. Seems that after upgrading from the beta iOS7 to the official release, the e-mail that I use for iMessages was no longer set on the phone. Thanks a bunch!